# Github branch protection rules/status checks

Tags: github, github-actions

I'd like to create a branch protection rule for our main branch in a way that if the "enforce-pr-naming-convention" github workflow fails for a pull request event, the pull request merge button should be disabled. Though the workflow is present in .github/workflows , was tested and works fine, I can't see & select it under settings/branches.
expectation:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmRPS.png
reality:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRoi6.png

Any idea on how to solve this?